# How do I write custom color coding?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5

I'm using this code in my **viewDidLoad** method for my **UserCreationViewController**

```
NSDictionary *textAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                [UIColor greenColor],NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                [UIColor blackColor],NSBackgroundColorAttributeName,nil];

self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = textAttributes;
self.title = @"User Creation";
```

What I want to know is, and I understand that I can change the UIColor to redColor, yellowColor(etc.), is how can I code my custom "color well" color.

*In other words*  How can I set the color if this navigationBar title to a custom color picked from the color well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following code:

```
UIColor *customColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:155.0/255.0 green:10.0/255.0 blue:50.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```

or

```
UIColor *customColor = [UIColor colorWithHue: 0.667 saturation: 1.0 brightness: 1.0 alpha: 1.0];
```

[More info.](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: I figured out the first line of code but thank you for the second, didn't know about that one. Ill give you answer for your time.